# External file with functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, include, external

how to add (and then use) external file in project directory which includes custom functions used in *.aspx.cs files?

I mean like in php - e.g. functions.php file and in other files `include/require_once('functions.php')`.

Is there any way to do this?

Or other way - how to use functions from one .aspx.cs file in the other one (of course without copying all of them ;))

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Write a class to encapsulate those functions, and instantiate the class where needed to use them.  Put the class file in the app_code folder.

Comment: Perhaps you want to reference a dll?

Comment: Are you using a Web Site (created with File-New Web Site), or a Web Application Project (created with File->New Project)? A Web Site may be more familiar to users of scripting languages like PHP, but they are little-understood by most other Microsoft developers.

Comment: @user1900685 C# isn't PHP. That's the first point. C# is a mature, fully object-oriented language and platform, and it's compiled rather than interpreted. You really need to learn more about what's an assembly, assembly references, classes, namespaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by creating a separate class with all functions which needs to be shared.  This class should reside in "App_code" folder, which allows to use this class only in that particular "web application". Another option is to create a new "class library" and include the class in it, and "add reference" to the class library in any web application.

Note: As you may already know, functions should be like utility functions. For ex: for webforms application, you cannot refer asp.net controls outside the page.

Also, if three are no fields to be initialized for this shared class, consider create "static" class with "static" functions which are easy to call.